# Logging to custom logger in ANTLR 3.5

Tags: antlr, antlr3

By default, parser classes generted by ANTLR 3.5 write the error entries in SystemErr log. Is there a way to direct these entries to custom logger like based Log4J.

Answer (score 0):

In your Grammar file write:

```
    @members {
    private static org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("ClassName");
    }

    @rulecatch{
      catch(RecognitionException rex) {
        logger.error("Failed ", rex);
      }
    }

// rules
```